# How to share a Putty session with someone else?

Tags: command-line, ssh, remote-desktop

I'm looking for something like VNC for a command line interface. Specifically, I'd like to be able to share an ssh session (say via Putty) with someone else, working from another office across the country. We'd both be able to type things into the console, and see what the other one's doing (including more complex things things like vim and top). It seems to me that for such a thing a fully graphical VNC is an overkill. Is there any way to set this up?

Answer (score 8):

[multiuser screen](http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser) - it requires nothing on the client.